# Fullcalendar and angular.js adding event data to a form template on dayClick?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to figure out how to create a scope inside my controller that will basically show a form with event data whenever a user clicks on a calendar cell with data inside it.

I'm using the same form template that's hidden inside a div. Right now I have it set up that when a user clicks on a day on the calendar the form shows. I'm having trouble displaying the proper data inside the form inputs.

Here's a plunkr to show what I'm talking about: http://plnkr.co/edit/PQCrIfj8CTTTrvaALjq6?p=preview

Comment: modified demo  http://plnkr.co/edit/3gbGpDJlprG1A5ZojFzG?p=preview

Comment: This is incredible. Thanks a lot!